# Find vector components with norm

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Hi I would like to find the vector components of F with theses informations.

[image]

I'm able to find the angle on the Z axe of 32 degree but not with the x and y axes.

How can i do this thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the vector $\vec F$ is directed from $A=(0,0,10)$ to $B=(5,-3,0)$ so in the same direction of the vector

$$
\overrightarrow{AB}=(5,-3,-10)
$$
so, find the unit vector $\vec u=\frac{\overrightarrow{AB}}{|\overrightarrow{AB}|}$ and you have: $\vec F=|F| \vec u$ .

Comment: alright thank you very much!

Comment: Yes. Sorry my mistake! I edit